# Oracle reverse index and query

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

If I create a reverse index in Oracle on a VARCHAR2 column do I also need to reverse the value used in the WHERE clause?

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON myTable(name) REVERSE;

SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE name='Peter';
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE name='reteP';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it to improve the data distribution.

Like, many movie names begin with `The` which would degrade the index performance.

You don't need to reverse the condition: `Oracle` will do it for you automatically.

However, you cannot do range queries anymore:

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE name BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'
```

will result in a full scan

Comment: Thanks - that's kind of what I figured.

Answer (score 5):

The value you are searching for is 'Peter'.  If you search for 'reteP' you will return zero rows (or at least not the rows you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

No you don't - see [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_reverse_key_indexes_dml_insert.htm) for the full skinny.